# Android DecimalFormat rounding error: Random decimals added

Tags: android, format, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a number. It can have from 2 to 6 decimal.

If I pass a number without decimal, the results is ok.
Otherwise it adds random decimals.

```
    float value = ...;

    DecimalFormat formatter_currency = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols nf = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  

    nf.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    nf.setGroupingSeparator(',');

    formatter_currency.setDecimalFormatSymbols(nf);
    formatter_currency.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
    formatter_currency.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    return formatter_currency.format(value);
```

eg: 
value = 35 -> 35.00

value = 35.6 -> 35.65932558 (expected 35.60)

value = 35.659 -> 35.68899918 (expected 35.659)

I've read that probably is a problem with the float variable.
I've try with a double, but the result is the same.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide your imports in the code sample?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this quick test program and it seems to pass all of your test cases:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class FormatTest { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        double value = 35.659;

        DecimalFormat formatter_currency = new DecimalFormat();
        DecimalFormatSymbols nf = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  

        nf.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        nf.setGroupingSeparator(',');

        formatter_currency.setDecimalFormatSymbols(nf);
        formatter_currency.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
        formatter_currency.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        System.out.println(formatter_currency.format(value));
    }
}
```

Please try compiling it on your machine and try putting in different values. I basically just tried it with a `double` instead of a `float`. Please let me know if you see the same results as with the code you posted above.

Comment: `floats` are represented the same way as `doubles`, just with half the storage space and the evident accompanying loss of precision.

Comment: @Holmes I do understand that, I'm just saying I was unable to reproduce the issue when switching floats and doubles, which contradicts what the OP stated in the question.

Comment: It's better but still not accurate. I've tried with 35.63 and the output was 35.63000107